# How can I as a user flag/vote for questions to be migrated?

Tags: support, migration

I would like to help Stack Exchange out by flagging/voting for questions to be migrated to an appropriate site. How does this work and how can I do this?

Comment: Any example? We don't just migrate stuff around for the fun of it - anything specific on your mind?

Comment: I've made a bit of a substantial edit there Sangeet. Could you have a look if that's what you wanted to ask? If not, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: Just read following link, it shows that its not very obvious to select  questions for migration, http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F171549%2Fquestions-migrated-correctly&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFF2j1g8Qc_H3bpeU1JLqpLmBNAeg

Comment: So you're asking how to migrate to a site that's not on the list of targets? (If so, flag for moderator attention and mention the site you think is an appropriate target).

Comment: When a user is writing a question on any of the SE websites, I want to suggest him on which possible sites he can ask his question (if they are more suitable then his current website). Thanks!!

Comment: Please let me know if I can do this, can I float a survey, on this website regarding this. Thanks!!

Comment: Please only do this for questions that are off topic on the site they were posted on. If they're on topic but just *maybe* better suited somewhere else, don't tell the poster, because that usually just leads to cross posting (which is not allowed).

Comment: @Sangeeta I updated the duplicate into a much better FAQ just for this question. :)

Answer (score 2):

For new users, you can downvote and leave a comment about how the question should be closed.

Users with 3K+ rep can vote to close a question with the option of moving it.  For example:

### Vote to close

[image: Vote to Close Dialog Page 1]

### Choose "This question belongs on another site in the stack exchange network"

[image: Vote to Close Dialog Page 2]

### Choose where it should go

[image: Vote to Close Dialog Page 3]

Comment: Your second screenshot is misleading. To migrate,you actually have to select the "This question belongs on another site" option. Any of the other options would *not* migrate the question.

Comment: @animuson You're right.  I added another screenshot.

Comment: -1. No freehand cyrcles

Comment: @user000001 I know its not freehand, but I just added some details onto the images themselves using [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html)